# if-else statement in python django

Tags: python, django, orm

I am new to Django and I have a problem that I couldn't solve. I am trying to display a specific question and other related attribute from my Question model based on a field from the Participant model. The issue here is that it directly goes to the else statement even when the condition is true.I tried to print(participant.condition) and it works so I am not sure why its not working with the if statement.

```
@login_required
def LPSC_VIEW1(request):
    participant=request.user.participant
    if participant.condition == 'LPN':
        First_question= Question.objects.get(id=1)
        all_choices = First_question.choices.all()
        context = {'First_question': First_question, 'all_choices': all_choices}
        return render(request, 'study/FirstQN.html', context)
    else:
        First_question= Question.objects.get(id=12)
        all_choices = First_question.choices.all()
        context = {'First_question': First_question, 'all_choices': all_choices}
        return render(request, 'study/FirstQSC.html', context)
```

my models as the following:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="this is a caption")
    choices = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)
    vis_image = models.ImageField(default= "this is an image", null=False, blank=False, upload_to="static/study/img")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Condition(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Participant(models.Model): 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    condition = models.ForeignKey(Condition, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

Comment: does `if participant.condition.name == 'LPN':` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`condition` is a foreign key, not a string. You're comparing it against `'LPN'`, but no instance of your `Condition` model will be equal to that string.

Try `if participant.condition.name == 'LPN':` to compare the name field on the `Condition` instance to that string.

Your `print` statement shows them as apparently being the same because you've defined how to present `Condition` instances as strings with your `__str__` method - it will print the name for the `Condition` instance, but that doesn't mean that the `Condition` value is actually equal to that string.

Answer (score 2):

You must change this:

```
participant=request.user.participant
```

to:

```
participant=Participant.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use

```
from .models import Participant
participant = Participant.objects.get(user = request.user)
```

Comment: already on my view and participant has been created in another view

Comment: Django queries the database at the time of render, if it is in a different view it won't be accessed in another, you have to query it everytime you need it

Comment: thanks, but this did not solve the problem